# How to use binary_search on STL map

Tags: c++, dictionary

im wondering if you can use the STL binary_search on STL map. I've tried but still cant get it to work

```
map<int,string> dataMap;

if(binary_search (dataMap.begin().first, dataMap.end().first, key))
    // do some stuff
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Er, why would you want to? [`map<>::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find), [`map<>::lower_bound()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/lower_bound), [`map<>::upper_bound()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/upper_bound), and [`map<>::equal_range()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/equal_range) are more than sufficient.

Comment: Hi there, so are you suggesting to use lower_bound() or upper_bound() to implement a binary search? Able to give an example of how to implement it? Why is find() more efficient? i thought it does a linear search? so it is basically O(n) where as binary search is probably O(log n)

Comment: @dupdupdup `std::map` is normally implemented using a binary tree. `std::map::find` (the member function, not the standard algorithm) performs a binary search to find the key.

Comment: @dupdupdup : The pages I linked to specifically state the complexity requirements. "***Complexity:** Logarithmic in the size of the container.*"

Comment: @dupdupdup A bit of advise. If your look ups and insertions are not mixed, Scott Meyers recommends using sorted vector instead of map in Effective STL 'Item 23: Consider replacing associative containers with sorted vectors'. (http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/cplusplus/9780321545183/associative-containers/ch03lev1sec5)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

STL `map` is inherently a binary search tree - just use `map::find`. Using container member functions, where they are present, is preferable to algorithms.

Comment: oh is using find is as efficient as O(log n)?

Comment: but what if the key is basic_string type? Still binary search would be done?

Comment: @user2134488 yes, that's how templates work - unless specialized for a type, an STL container functions independent of the type

Answer (score 3):

Use `std::map::lower_bound`, `std::map::find` and `std::map::upper_bound` instead.

```
if(binary_search (dataMap.begin().first, dataMap.end().first, key))
```

binary_serach requires iterator. `dataMap.begin().first` and `dataMap.end().first` are not iterators. Another problem is that accessing `dataMap.end().first` is very likely to crash your application.